# My slideshow website only works when clicking the button twice to run the JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I would like to have my slideshow work with a single click, but only works with two clicks.

Here is my code:

var index=0;
var titles=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

```
function moveToNextSlide()
{
if (index >= 10){index=0}
var img = document.getElementById("img1");
var slideName="images/img" + titles[index++] + ".jpg";
img.src=slideName;
}
```

}

HTML CODE IS:

```
 <input type="button" onClick="javascript:moveToNextSlide()" value="Next">




<input type="button" onClick="javascript:moveToLastSlide()" value="Last">




<input type="button" onClick="javascript:moveToRandom()" value="Random"> </p>


<script>
moveToNextSlide();
moveToPreviousSlide();
</script>
```

Comment: can u just show us the html part?

Comment: And the click event handler?

Comment: <input type="button" onClick="javascript:moveToPreviousSlide()" value="Previous">
    
    
     <input type="button" onClick="javascript:moveToNextSlide()" value="Next">
   

        
 
 <input type="button" onClick="javascript:moveToLastSlide()" value="Last">
    

    
  
 <input type="button" onClick="javascript:moveToRandom()" value="Random"> </p>
    
    
    <script>
 moveToNextSlide();
 moveToPreviousSlide();
 </script>

Comment: that is the html part of it their is more of it if you need it

Comment: i dont understand why i need to click twice for the script to run

Comment: Put your code inside your question please.

Comment: maybe you should do var slideName="images/img" + titles[++index] + ".jpg";

Comment: thank @Anton it worked your greeat :DDDDD

Comment: I will put this connent as an answer

Comment: var index=0;
var titles=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

 function moveToNextSlide()
 {
 if (index >= 10){index=0}
 var img = document.getElementById("img1");
 var slideName="images/img" + titles[++index] + ".jpg";
 img.src=slideName;
 }
 
  that has worked good thank you - it is the correct your help anton

Comment: approve my answer please )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do var slideName="images/img" + titles[++index] + ".jpg";

Answer (score -1):

You need to do this

```
var slideName="images/img" + titles[++index] + ".jpg";
```

Always declare variables it is a good programming practice